# Why write a followup set of empty parenthesis when using IIFE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to JS. Using jonhpapa's Angular style guide and I noticed that when he suggests using the IIFE closure he always adds an extra set of empty parenthesis. Why?

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('logger', logger);

function logger() { }
})();
```

Comment: Because it's not an IIFE unless you do.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment - this is an example of a named function:

```
function x() { console.log('x'); }
```

In order to invoke the function, you need to add parenthesis after it's name like this:

```
x();
```

You do the same thing to unnamed functions in order to invoke them:

```
(function() { console.log('x'); })();
```

Comment: Ah okay, I was used to working with named functions only - it's crystal clear now thanks!